# How to delete duplicates within a large database on a column by column basis

Tags: excel, database, duplicates

I have a large set of data (over 3000 columns) for work, with text in every cell. Each column is unrelated to each other. Within each column there are potentially duplicates and I need to keep only the first instance , but there is no way to highlight the cells with duplicates on a column by column basis as when the whole data set is highlighted excel treats the rows as related data and looks for duplicates on a row by row basis. I have tried using macros (I am a total novice) but the macros don't work.

[Image shows the columns of data with some duplicates in the columns.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX3vE.png)

Comment: What kind of insanity is dumping thousands of unrelated columns into excel and then referring to it as a database... I strongly suspect this is an XY problem, but to do what you ask you'll need to iterate through every single cell in every column create a dictionary per column and delete the cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the modern Excel, you could use the `UNIQUE` function, which returns the array of unique elements.

Just duplicate the sheet and in the copy delete everything below the lines with "Processor 1" and "Processor 2". Then in the first column use `UNIQUE` referring to the first respective column of the original sheet.

Just fill the formula right (Ctrl + R) and in the new sheet each column will have only the unique elements.

You can then paste the whole resulting table as values and delete the original one.

Comment: Fantastic worked great! I've struggled with this for a while, I had to do it on excel online as our excel isn't up to date enough.